# Looking for a way to parse values in springboot application.yml file before SpringBootApplication is initialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

So my problem is as follows:

I'm using spring AMQP to connect to a rabbitMQ instance that using SSL.  Unfortunately, spring AMQP does not currently support full length amqps URIs and adding support is not high on the priority list (see issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6401 ).  They need to be separated.

The following fields are required in my application.yml to connect:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: hostname
    port: portnumber
    username: username
    password: password
    virtual-host: virtualhost
    ssl:
      enabled: true
```

My VCAP_Services environment for my rabbitMQ instance only provides the virtualhost and the full length uri in the following format: `amqps://username:password@hostname:portnumber/virtualhost`

Copy and pasting these values into my application.yml is fine for now, but in the long run is not viable.  They will need to come from vcap_services.

My @SpringBootApplication has @Beans that initialize a connection to the rabbitMQ instance on startup, so I am looking for a way to parse out the individual values and set them before the application is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just interested in reading the properties before your Spring Boot application is initialized, you can parse the yaml file using Spring's `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` before you call `SpringApplication.run`. For example,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlFactory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yamlFactory.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yml"));
        Properties props = yamlFactory.getObject();

        String hostname = props.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.hostname");
        ...

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: While I did go with Gary's solution, I'm accepting this because it answers the original question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply override Boot's auto configured connection factory...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So46937522Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So46937522Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(RabbitProperties config)
            throws Exception {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory()
            .setUri("amqps://guest:guest@10.0.0.3:5671/virtualhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "si.test.queue")
    public void listen(Message in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Gary, this worked well and is originally what I was looking for, though the ConnectionFactory class didn't seem to have the getRabbitConnectionFactory method, so I didn't look into it that much.  This seems like the best solution to the linked github issue as well.